# CSS Bootstrap MegaMenu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a megamenu dropdown, but is it with some bugs.

**Problems:**

-The li tags inside sub-menu are not appearing.

-Mouse Hover on sub-menu and main menu border disappear.

**Images**

Mouse hover main menu:
[image]

Mouse hover sub-menu:
[image]

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainMenu">
  <!-- Main navigation -->
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
    <li class="primary <?php if($page == 'main'){ echo 'active'; } ?>">
      <a href="./?page=main" class="firstLevel last" >Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="primary <?php if($page == 'about'){ echo 'active'; } ?>">
      <a href="./?page=about" class="firstLevel last" >About us</a>                 
    </li>
    <li class="primary">
      <a href="#" class="drop">Features</a><!-- Begin 4 columns Item -->
      <div class="dropdown_4columns align_right"><!-- Begin 4 columns container -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h3>Technical</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">ThemeForest</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">GraphicRiver</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ActiveDen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">VideoHive</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3DOcean</a></li>
          </ul>   

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">

          <h3>Design</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">NetTuts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">VectorTuts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PsdTuts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PhotoTuts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ActiveTuts</a></li>
          </ul>   

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">

          <h3>Software</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">FreelanceSwitch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Creattica</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">WorkAwesome</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mac Apps</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Web Apps</a></li>
          </ul>   

        </div>         
      </div><!-- End 4 columns container -->
    </li>
    <li class="primary <?php if($page == 'portfolio'){ echo 'active'; } ?>"><a href="./?page=portfolio" class="firstLevel last">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li class="primary <?php if($page == ''){ echo 'active'; } ?>"><a href="" class="firstLevel last">Downloads</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!-- End main navigation -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#mainMenu .navbar-nav li{
 border-bottom:1px solid #555;
}
#mainMenu .navbar-nav li:last-child,
#mainMenu .navbar-nav li:last-child a{
 border-bottom:none !important;
}

#mainMenu li:hover {
    background:none;
    border:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
 
#mainMenu li a {
    display:block;
    outline:0;
    text-decoration:none;
}
 
#mainMenu li:hover a {
    color:#161616;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFFFFF;
}

 
/* Drop Down */
  
.dropdown_4columns{
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    display:none; /* Hides the drop down */
    text-align:left;
    border-top:none;
    background-color:#eee;
}
 
.dropdown_4columns {width: 560px;}
 
#mainMenu li:hover .dropdown_4columns{
    display:block;
    top:auto;

}

#mainMenu li:hover .align_right {
    left:auto;
    right:-1px;
    top:auto;
}
 
/* Drop Down Content Stylings */
 
#mainMenu p, #mainMenu h2, #mainMenu h3, #mainMenu ul li {
    line-height:21px;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:left;
}
#mainMenu h2 {
    font-size:21px;
    font-weight:400;
    letter-spacing:-1px;
    margin:7px 0 14px 0;
    padding-bottom:14px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #666666;
}
#mainMenu h3 {
    font-size:14px;
    margin:7px 0 14px 0;
    padding-bottom:7px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #888888;
}
#mainMenu p {
    line-height:18px;
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
}
 
#mainMenu li:hover div a {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#015b86;
}
#mainMenu li:hover div a:hover {
    color:#029feb;
}

#mainMenu li ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 0 0px 0;
}
#mainMenu li ul li {
    position:relative;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    float:none;
    text-align:left;
 display:block;
}
#mainMenu li ul li:hover {
    background:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus{
 background:none;
 border-bottom:3px solid #984793;
 color:#984793;
}
```

Comment: try to add .clearfix to UL

Comment: Didn't worked, i added to all UL in menu @Chandrakant

Comment: hmm could you please create jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/cdnrjd3o/
@Chandrakant

Comment: Ok, here's a bootply of it - what's wrong with it? Your question is not clear to me http://www.bootply.com/XtUsuP86xp

Comment: Yes, I found where was the error and had not seen. But the borders remain with the same bug.

Comment: I cant solve the border problem. @DarrenSweeney

Comment: Check answer submitted @Paulosá

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this css:

```css
#mainMenu .navbar-nav li:last-child,
#mainMenu .navbar-nav li:last-child a{
    border-bottom:none !important; /* this removes bottom border for last-child */
}
```

If you remove that it works as expected

[Here's a fiddle showing the fix](https://jsfiddle.net/qcke71hc/)

Comment: Yes, that was for sure one of the problems, but it's not working, i will look for some other errors

Comment: Added fiddle to the answer

Comment: It's working now, the submenu was behind the main menu. Thank you